# Dual monitors - primary monitor rotates 90 degrees counterclockwise (I DON'T WANT IT TO), secondary does not

Tags: windows-7, extended-desktop, display-rotation

Well, you can pretty much read the problem in the title. I have a laptop and a monitor, and when I want to use them in the extended mode, the laptop screen decides to rotate to a portrait orientation, even though it is set to landscape.. It used to work properly, and all of a sudden this issue started to happen. I would really appreciate if you could help me solve this problem, since I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Oh, and, I use windows 7 on my laptop. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You probably hit a shortcut key combination that rotated your display.  Check the documentation for your laptop, and/or go into the graphics portion of control panel to change it back.

Comment: I know about the ctrl+alt+home (page up, page down, end) combination, but I didn't go near those keys :D the thing is, if I choose apply after I select 'extended monitors' the screen 1 rotates, and it asks me if I want to keep changes or to revert them. I would have to click 'keep changes' in order to access the orientation settings, but I'm worried if I would be able to rotate it back to normal position. :/ How do I access the graphic portion od control panel? :) sorry if it is a stupid question..

Comment: Depends.  Some video cards/drivers have their own... plug-in/control panel section, some don't.  If your doesn't, then the part you described above is where you need to go.

Comment: I've succeeded :D I clicked 'keep changes' and then I saw it was actually set on portrait, which I couldn't change before :) and I simply selected landscape, and it worked :) thank you so much :)

Comment: The only thing is, it messed the order of my icons on the desktop, but that's an easy fix, so it's ok now :)

Comment: pretty sure ctrl-alt-arrows does this also. used to do that by mistake all the time being a linux user.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the arrow combination too :) the thing was, I had to accept the changes first, in order to SEE that it was PORTRAIT mode (before I accepted them, it said it was set to landscape). And only then I could change it to landscape :) thank you all :)

Comment: Awesome. Well write up your own answer here and accept it in 24 hours. That way superuser has another question that future users can look upon ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy fix actually. All I had to do was:
1) select extended monitors (in display settings)
2) click apply
3) **click keep changes** - when I did that, the screen on my laptop stayed rotated, but then I was able to change orientation. (I couldn't access those options without keeping the changes first, and since it said it was in landscape mode, I thought something was wrong, since it was obviously showing as portrait)
4) click 'orientation' dropbox
5) select 'landscape'
That's it :)
Thank you all for your help and quick response :)